One second stage covariate is endogenous to first stage regression
I am working on a database (regional level, call it DB) in order to analyse determinants of modal choice for commuting. I run a multinomial logit : I regress mode choice (car, bike, walk, PT, carpooling) on some individual variables (age, type of job, place of residence, working from home...) and some variables at the firm level (infrastructure in favor of active mode, accessibility in PT...).
Doing so, I might face an issue of reverse causality : it might be possible that the mode used for commuting have an impact on the fact to work from home (I bike to work but it's a bit too much so I decide to work from home one day a week). Working from home is one of my variables of interest.
I constructed thus an instrument to control this problem of endogeneity. I use a national database on employment (call it NT) and compute the share of people who work from home by sector of employment (industry, administration, health,...). Each respondent of my database DB is then associated with this national share of people who work from home in the sector corresponding to its firm. This instrument might do the trick : it is uncorrelated with individual mode choice as it comes from another database (national level) and is correlated with the fact that a respondent declares to work from home (firms of my database DB belong to sector).
My problem appears when I run my first stage regression : I regress my endogenous variable (the fact to work from home at least partly) on all the exogenous variables of my main regression. Among those variables, we find distance of commuting and place of residence. Nonetheless, another issue of endogeneity might appear here : distance of commuting and place of residence can affect the fact to work from home (I tend to more work from home because I commute on a long distance).
I am now a bit lost about how to deal with this situation. I am quite sure that I absolutely need to add all the exogenous variables of my second stage in my first stage regression. But I am also sure that the estimate in my first stage has to be consistent, which is not the case.
Any help would be more than welcome !!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
